# How to write half-space in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I write the `half-space` character in c# in a `Textbox` (not `Console.Writleline` statement) ? Is there a specific char code for it?

Comment: Not even sure what you mean. Is that a specific unicode character?

Comment: Whatever character you mean, in a fixed-spaced font display (such as a regular Windows console window), all characters, even those intended to be half-width, will take up the same space. [Every single Unicode space character](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) will be the same size. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I wonder why you want such specific characters to be output to `Console.WriteLine()` in a WPF application. Are you showing a GUI _and_ a console to your end users?

Comment: Sorry, I asked it in a bad way. I want it to be displayed in textbox.

Comment: I still have never heard of such a character, can you provide an example of it outside C#?

Comment: What is half-space to you? Check this link: https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html and let us know.

Comment: It is a space that is a little thinner than the regular space.

Comment: @heh How can I write these in c#?

Comment: @Vahid, please see my answer. I believe it will work for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unicode THINSPACE U+2009 is a perfectly ordinary character, try:

```
TextBox.Text += '\u2009';
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, because pasting it from e.g. your browser into e.g. Visual Studio converts it to a normal space. Plus it's a lot clearer for someone who reads the code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by half-space, but `Char.Parse()` will probably do what you want. Please get a list of [Unicode spaces](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html)

Then do this (example is for 1/2 en space; remove all plus signs):

```
string UnicodeString = "\u2000"; // U+2000
TextBox.Text = Char.Parse(UnicodeString);
```

However, you probably don't need `Char.Parse()` for this. You could simply do this:

```
string halfSpace = "\u2000"; // So you can reuse it
TextBox.Text = halfSpace;
```

**UPDATE**: If you want to add it to the `TextBox` (`+=`), rather than replacing the whole line (`=`), use this:

```
TextBox.Text += halfSpace
```